# Is it possible to set the draft mode of a document AFTER \documentclass

Tags: document-classes, preamble, draft, document-configuration

I am using a precompiled preamble with the \documentclass inside. However, I sometimes want to change the document to 'draftmode'. Recompile the preamble everytime I am doing this is not so comfortable. So it is somehow possible to activate the draftmode even after the command \documentclass in the preamble?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but it may depend on what you mean by "recompile the preamble". Can you provide some code that explains your setup and how you change things to switch between `draft` and non-`draft` mode at the moment?

Comment: Try `\PassOptionsToClass{draft}{article}`  before the precompiled preamble

Comment: My code looks overall 'normal'  I just use Mylatexformat which creates a .fmt file which consits of the preloaded preamble (so loading all the usepackages etc.) I also added the \documentclass in this precompiling so everytimt I  have to change something inside documentclass I can do so but then recompile it again to make changes take effect. Besides this my code is completely normal I can still disable the function and run the code in the normal way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full definition of the `draft` option in the standard classes is

```
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
```

so you can get the equivalent effect by doing

```
\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}
```

at any point.

However using `[draft]` on document class makes it a global option so it may have had an effect on packages you have loaded (but you have not given any information on which packages).

Most packages will ignore it, some may just set a flag to true for draft mode, in which case you may be able to set that flag to false, but some packages may alter the code loading and so not load the "normal" code at all in draft mode. The behaviour is all specific to each packages handling of any `draft` option that it has.